# Can you trace what sites a program is opening

Tags: internet

I use Dell Support Assist on my computers to keep them updated. The problem is that some of the users are not allowed internet access and when you run Support Assist it almost immediately comes back with a "Download Failed" error. I believe one of the first things it does is check for updates to Support Assist and that is where it fails.

Dell support, as always, is worthless. Is there a way to see what sites Support Assist is trying to go to so I can whitelist them in the firewall?

Comment: Try Wireshark to see packets that are not getting out. You need a packet sniffer to do this,

Comment: How can whitelisting in the firewall help if there is no internet?

Comment: I can give them access to any site I want. I am using content filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a network, some computers are allowed network access (SupportAssist works) and some on your network are not allowed Interenet access (SupportAssist fails).

SupportAssist is a web tool, and without Interenet access, it will fail.  You did not indicate how or why some computers are not permitted to have Internet access. I will make a guess they do have LAN access.

However you have that restriction designed, you need to allow permission for SupportAssist to run on the local pc with LAN/WAN access (if that's where you blocked it), or at the firewall/network for the websites that it needs to connect to.

If you don't know what websites it connects to you can use wireshark, or something simple like TCP/IP viewer on the local PC once you enable all Internet access temporarily.

Comment: The problem is still the same but if you need more detail I am Content Filtering with a SonicWall TZ300, Some users are allowed internet access some aren't. It is "allowed" to run on all the computer. It is just an app. I have whitelisted dell.com but, as the question states, it needs access to some other site(s) as it "Fails to Download". The question really remains the same. So running Wireshark before running Support Assist should show me where Support Assist is trying to download from? Any others besides WireSHark?

Comment: I think you have a good idea how to identufy the issue.  I had same issue years ago to only allow a network specific web access, but found that website also called other websites, and that is where it failed.  I solved by tracking a computer with full permission and then using that info to adjust the firewall.